# Transforming list to the 'table' without duplicates in r

Tags: r

I have a long list containing tables of various lengths, like these ones:

```
[[1]]

16 21 28 36 47 49 51 62 71 80 87 93 95 
 4  2  1  2  1  3  1  1  1  1  2  2  1 

[[2]]

16 36 47 49 71 
 1  2  3  1  1 

[[3]]

 4 36 47 71 87 98 
 1  1  1  1  1  2 

[[4]]

16 21 47 49 56 62 71 80 87 93 
 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
```

I have attempted to transfer this list to the table using the following line:

```
do.call(c,loser)# where 'loser' is my list
```

which is nearly what I want.My current output is something like this:

```
16 21 28 36 47 49 51 62 71 80 87 93 95 16 36 47 49 71  4 36 47 71 87 98 16 21 
 4  2  1  2  1  3  1  1  1  1  2  2  1  1  2  3  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  2  1  1

47 49 56 62 71 80 87 93 21 28 36 49 56 62 64 80 87 93 21 36 47 49 64 80  4 36 
 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  2  1  1  2  1  2  4  1  1  1  1  1  2  1  1  1  1  1

 4 21 36 47 51 56 71 80 87 93 98 21 93 95  1 21 36 47 49 51 56 62 71 
 1  1  1  1  2  1  2  1  2  1  1  1  1  1  1  2  2  3  2  1  1  2  1
```

How can I merge the duplicates together so that I have only one '16' with one number to it, for example? Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: look at the function `unique()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possibile solution :

```
# recreated your list
L <- 
list(
setNames(c(4,2,1,2,1,3,1,1,1,1,2,2,1),c(16,21,28,36,47,49,51,62,71,80,87,93,95)),
setNames(c(1,2,3,1,1),c(16,36,47,49,71)),
setNames(c(1,1,1,1,1,2),c(4,36,47,71,87,98)),
setNames(c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),c(16,21,47,49,56,62,71,80,87,93)) 
)

# create a single vector
v <- unlist(L)
# aggregate the values by summing values with same name
v <- ave(v,names(v),FUN=sum)[!duplicated(names(v))]

# > v
# 16 21 28 36 47 49 51 62 71 80 87 93 95  4 98 56 
#  6  3  1  5  6  5  1  2  4  2  4  3  1  1  2  1
```

Comment: That's great! Is there a way to recreate the list automatically rather then me doing it manually?

Comment: Wait... you should already have your list defined. I just recreated the list you posted in order to make my example complete and runnable, but the first part of my code should not be used by you. Just replace `L` with the name of your list everywhere in the code ;)

Answer (score 1):

Using @digEmAll's sample data, try:

```
xtabs(unlist(L, use.names = FALSE) ~ names(unlist(L)))
## names(unlist(L))
## 16 21 28 36  4 47 49 51 56 62 71 80 87 93 95 98 
##  6  3  1  5  1  6  5  1  1  2  4  2  4  3  1  2
```